# Benefits of using backtick (`) in MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql, select

In MySQL we can create queries with or without the backtick (`` ` ``) symbol. Example:

1. `SELECT * FROM TEST;`
2. `` SELECT * FROM `TEST`; ``

Both works fine in mysql-console.

Is there any technical difference between them?

Is there any benefit using (`` ` ``) over over simple queries?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

They are called quoted identifiers and they tell the parser to handle the text between them as a literal string. They are useful for when you have a column or table that contains a keyword or space. For instance the following would not work:

```
CREATE TABLE my table (id INT);
```

But the following would:

```
CREATE TABLE `my table` (id INT);
```

Also, the following would get an error, because `COUNT` is a reserved keyword:

```
SELECT count FROM some_table
```

But the following would be parsed correctly:

```
SELECT `count` FROM some_table
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 31):

If you want to use something around object identifiers, use at least the standard double quotes: "

This works in MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc. etc. For MySQL you might need the [SQL mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html) [ansi_quotes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes), depending on the default configuration:

```
SET sql_mode = 'ANSI_QUOTES';
```

Backticks ` are only used in MySQL, you learn a type of SQL that won't work in any other brand of DBMS.

Comment: Using quotes will throw a SQL syntax error in MySQL/MariaDb without sql_mode ANSI_QUOTES

Answer (score 7):

It means you can have spaces in table names. Not particular appealing, of course. Same with SQL Server's [].

Answer (score 5):

It can be helpful if you have a column with name that is reserved,

eg: 
You can query a statement like this:

```
select * from tablename group by `group`;
```

Answer (score 4):

From my point of view, @Mr.Brownstone answer is only partially correct.

The backtick `` ` `` is used in MySQL to delimit literals that represent identifiers (not strings).

This allows you to use not usually accepted characters like spaces, reserved words, etc. as identifiers. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM `Strange table name`;
```

Also important is that it also allows the parser to know if you are doing something wrong like selecting a column that doesn't exist. For example:

```
SELECT notexistingcolumn FROM atable;
```

If `atable` exists but `notexistingcolumn` column doesn't exist it will be interpreted as the literal string "notexistingcolumn" selecting it as a value (and probably emitting a warning).

Instead, if you use:

```
SELECT `notexistingcolumn` FROM `atable`;
```

It will recognize that `notexistingcolumn` is the name of a column that doesn't exist and throw an error.

I think is always preferable to surround identifiers with backticks including the alias and try to avoid using reserved words and strange characters for identifiers.

You can read more about the [MySQL backtick](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html).