# Reading .sql file from Postgres restore function

Tags: postgresql, restore

I've received the following .sql file plus some extra files:

[image: First folder content]

Here is the content of the Entities folder:

[image: Content of Entities folder]

I've installed PostgreSQL and within the pgAdmin tool I do "restore" and fill the fields as follows:

[image]:

But I get the following error:

[image]

Any idea?

#### UPDATE

I've managed to run the .sql import using the following command:

```
\i 'C:/.../.database.sql
```

But I get a lot of errors as below:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just run the .sql using psql or pgadmin. No need to restore it.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. When you say "just run" do you mean:
1) to run it from SQL Shell?
2) to run it as a query?
3) something else?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, but this won't work. The error messages in your console show that the SQL is using backticks (`` ` ``), which is a [distinctive feature of MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23132/67785), a different type of SQL database. While both systems understand (ANSI) SQL, they use their own 'flavours' / 'dialects' which are not fully compatible with each other.

The simplest solution for you is to install MySQL instead. If you want to stick with PostgreSQL, there are tools available to convert between different database types (even free ones); how well they work depends from case to case.

Comment: ok thanks for your suggestion. I'm downloading MySql and I'll let you know.

Comment: I worked. MySQL is more intuitive and easy to use. Importing the .sql file is super easy. thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Sebastian: no wonder importing the data with MySQL was easier to do if the export was intended for MySQL. If it was a Postgres dump, it would have been as easy as running `psql ... -f dump.sql`